# What Linux Window Manager supports management of window by application itself?

Tags: linux, window-manager, window-decorations

Is there a Linux WM that supports management of window by application itself? I would like to have the following:

[image]

Instead of:

[image]

With a small screen laptop, it would be nice to save some extra screen space. I tried searching on the web, but got no results.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Well... I found the answer. Apparently, it seems to be in-app settings and it is independent on WM. Posting here the solution for VS Code and Firefox for anyone who is interested:

- VS Code: The relevant setting is `window.titleBarStyle: "custom"`
- Firefox: `Menu->Customize->Uncheck "Title Bar"`
- Chrome: Is set by default without the WM title bar

Tested with Openbox WM. Not sure about stability on other WMs...